# Assign value to dropdown list via query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik

I stored the selected value in a DDL list on Page 1 in query string variable and then tried to assign it on page 2, to the same drop down list coming from user control page. But while assigning the value to the DDList on page 2 I am getting either an array index out of bound exception or a null value exception.

I have debugged and verified that the query string is correct, but it is unable to assign this value to the ddl list.Code pasted below:

```
 <telerik:RadComboBox 
      ID="cmbSearchOaO" 
      runat="server"
      AutoPostBack="true"
      AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
      Width="200px"
      DataSourceID="odsOwnedAndOperated"
      DataTextField="Owned_And_Operated_Nm"
      DataValueField="Owned_And_Operated_Id"
      OnSelectedIndexChanged="PopulateApplicationTypeDropDown">
 </telerik:RadComboBox>


  ddl2.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["No2"];           
  ddl2.FindItemByValue(Request.QueryString["No2"].ToString()).Selected = true;
```

The correct value is populated in `Request.QueryString["No2"]` , but I need to store it on LHS i.e on ddl list.

Comment: did you check if before assigning selected value to ddl2 this dropdownlist has items? Basically the error occurs if you're trying to assign selected value on it while it has no items yet.

Comment: @ Jobert Enamno : yes..Actually the ddl list is used from a user control. to 2 diff pages.when I am passing the values..ddl list is not showing any values. let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: meaning your page 1 and page 2 are just using 1 ddl which is in a usercontrol?

Comment: Yes @Jobert Enamno ..8 such ddl list are there. the scenario is if after selecting all/some of  the ddllist in page 1 if I am clicking on a particular button it should redirect me to page 2 . where all the 8 ddl list of page2 should get the same value from page 1..I am getting the value in page 2 by query string.....but my problem is only with assigning it with ddllist's selected item.

Comment: another question. Is your ddl items static or constant or the items are dynamically populated from database or other source?

Comment: ddls are populated from database..

Comment: Okay I posted answer below please explore if this works for you. Also make sure that your dropdownlist is populated before assigning selected value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution. In my example I used ASP.NET DropdownList control

**User control that holds the dropdownlist to be used by page1 and page 2**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DDlUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.DDlUserControl" %>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="20px" 
    Width="223px">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Item 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Item 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Item 4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5">Item 5</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="6">Item 6</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="7">Item 7</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="8">Item 8</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**Page1 html page**

```
<p>
        <uc1:DDlUserControl ID="DDlUserControl1" runat="server" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" 
            Text="Go to Page 2" />
    </p>
```

**Page1 code behind**

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ddl = DDlUserControl1.FindControl("ddlTest") as DropDownList;
            Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?no="+ddl.SelectedValue);
        }
```

**Page2 html**

```
<div>

        This is page 2<br />
        <br />
        <uc1:DDlUserControl ID="DDlUserControl1" runat="server" />

    </div>
```

**Page2 code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedVal = Request.QueryString["no"];
            var ddl = DDlUserControl1.FindControl("ddlTest") as DropDownList;
            ddl.SelectedValue = selectedVal;
        }
```